# I just downloaded gnu clisp via the synaptic manager. Now how do i use it?

Tags: programming

So in windows, I got used to putting file names in my path variable and then using the interpreter/compiler from the commandline prompt. What's the equivalent on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in there official webpage:

http://www.clisp.org/